# Sum of values in a multiple lists of a dict

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, sum

I am new to python and have been trying to add values that I get from iterating over a list of dictionaries.

I keep running into 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable' error message or unsupported type. Any help would be much appreciated.

here is my code:

```
def inventory(acct_info, months_subscribed, add_free_months, video_on_demand):
     
  print(acct_info)


  for info in acct_info:
   
    print('-')
          
   


    
    if info.get('months_subscribed') == 3:
        months_subscribed_total = info.get('months_subscribed') * 18
    elif info.get('months_subscribed') < 3:
        months_subscribed_total = info['months_subscribed'] * 7
    elif info.get('months_subscribed') > 3:
        months_subscribed_total = info['months_subscribed'] - 3 * 7 + 18

    print(f"User {info.get('name')} has months subscribed total of : $ {months_subscribed_total} ")

    if info['ad_free_months'] > 0:

      ad_free_total = info.get('ad_free_months') * 2 
      print(f" User {info.get('name')} total ad free is : {ad_free_total} ")

    if info['video_on_demand'] > 0:
      video_on_demand_total = info.get('video_on_demand') * 27.99
      
      print(f" User {info.get('name')} total video on demand is : {video_on_demand_total} ")



      acct_all_total = int(months_subscribed_total + ad_free_total + video_on_demand_total)
      acct_all_total = [int(acct_all_total)]
      print(f"Total for {info.get('name')} is: {acct_all_total} ")  



  acct_info = [{'name': 'acct_1', 'months_subscribed' : 2 , 'ad_free_months' : 3 , 'video_on_demand' : 1} ,
                        {'name': 'acct_2', 'months_subscribed' : 1 , 'ad_free_months' : 2 , 'video_on_demand' : 2},
                        {'name': 'acct_3', 'months_subscribed' : 2 , 'ad_free_months' : 1 , 'video_on_demand' : 3}] 


  combined_total = 0
  months_subscribed = 0
  ad_free_months = 0
  video_on_demand = 0
  months_subscribed_total = 0
  ad_free_total = 0 
  video_on_demand_total = 0
  inventory(acct_info, months_subscribed, ad_free_months, video_on_demand)
  acct_all_total = 0


main()
```

Output so far is :

```
User acct_1 has months subscribed total of : $ 14 
 User acct_1 total ad free is : 6 
 User acct_1 total video on demand is : 27.99 
Total for acct_1 is: [47] 
-
User acct_2 has months subscribed total of : $ 7 
 User acct_2 total ad free is : 4 
 User acct_2 total video on demand is : 55.98 
Total for acct_2 is: [66] 
-
User acct_3 has months subscribed total of : $ 14 
 User acct_3 total ad free is : 2 
 User acct_3 total video on demand is : 83.97 
Total for acct_3 is: [99]
```

What i am trying to sum up is the total for all of the users. I manage to get a total for each user, but i then want add the totals of that. Thank you.

Comment: error `builtin_function_or_method` means you forgot `()` to execute function - ie. if you use `print` without `()` then you get similar message. But you didn't show full error message so I don't know which line makes this problem. And don't expect that we will run code to see errors. Besides it may run correctly on our computers.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: I run your code and it works without problems. Show code which gibes you error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take into consideration modifying your code a little bit your code.
I would move out the `for loop` from your function to make it do just one thing: do the inventory for a given account.
The following code is just an example, but it provides an alternative solution for your question.

```
def inventory(info, months_subscribed, add_free_months, video_on_demand):
    acct_all_total = 0 # here you init the total value to 0
    if info.get('months_subscribed') == 3:
        months_subscribed_total = info.get('months_subscribed') * 18
    elif info.get('months_subscribed') < 3:
        months_subscribed_total = info['months_subscribed'] * 7
    elif info.get('months_subscribed') > 3:
        months_subscribed_total = info['months_subscribed'] - 3 * 7 + 18

    print(f"User {info.get('name')} has months subscribed total of : $ {months_subscribed_total} ")

    if info['ad_free_months'] > 0:
        ad_free_total = info.get('ad_free_months') * 2
        print(f" User {info.get('name')} total ad free is : {ad_free_total} ")

    if info['video_on_demand'] > 0:
        video_on_demand_total = info.get('video_on_demand') * 27.99

        print(f" User {info.get('name')} total video on demand is : {video_on_demand_total} ")

        acct_all_total = int(months_subscribed_total + ad_free_total + video_on_demand_total)
        # acct_all_total = [int(acct_all_total)] 
        print(f"Total for {info.get('name')} is: {acct_all_total} ")
    return acct_all_total
```

Please note I also commented the `# acct_all_total = [int(acct_all_total)]`

Then you can call it

```
acct_info = [{'name': 'acct_1', 'months_subscribed': 2, 'ad_free_months': 3, 'video_on_demand': 1},
             {'name': 'acct_2', 'months_subscribed': 1, 'ad_free_months': 2, 'video_on_demand': 2},
             {'name': 'acct_3', 'months_subscribed': 2, 'ad_free_months': 1, 'video_on_demand': 3}]

combined_total = 0
months_subscribed = 0
ad_free_months = 0
video_on_demand = 0
months_subscribed_total = 0
ad_free_total = 0
video_on_demand_total = 0
acct_all_total = 0
for acct in acct_info:
    acct_all_total+=inventory(acct, months_subscribed, ad_free_months, video_on_demand)
print("Tot:",acct_all_total)
```

Output:

```
User acct_1 has months subscribed total of : $ 14 
 User acct_1 total ad free is : 6 
 User acct_1 total video on demand is : 27.99 
Total for acct_1 is: 47 
User acct_2 has months subscribed total of : $ 7 
 User acct_2 total ad free is : 4 
 User acct_2 total video on demand is : 55.98 
Total for acct_2 is: 66 
User acct_3 has months subscribed total of : $ 14 
 User acct_3 total ad free is : 2 
 User acct_3 total video on demand is : 83.97 
Total for acct_3 is: 99 
Tot: 212
```

Edited to reflect comments.

If you want to get the largest of your total, you have to change the code a bit. Consider to use the built-in function `max()` https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#max and `sum()` https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#sum.

`max()` returns the largest item in an iterable or the largest of two or more arguments. `sum()` sums all the element in an iterable. So, let's use an iterable in our code

```
 tot = list() 
for acct in acct_info:
    # here, we gonna append each total
    tot.append(inventory(acct, months_subscribed, ad_free_months, video_on_demand))
print("all the values:",tot)
print("the largest is:",max(tot)) # here we extract the largest item of the list
print("Total:",sum(tot)) # here we sum all the element of the list tot
```

Output:

```
all the values: [47, 66, 99]
the largest is: 99
Total: 212
```

Comment: I have modified my code, and it works. Now I am trying to get the max value in all of the individual totals . I am trying to use the max function such like : max(acct_all_total)   which is not possible, can someone please tell me why this is not possible and a potential solution to this?

Comment: the max() built-in function (https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#max) returns the largest item in an iterable or the largest of two or more arguments. You are just passing acct_all_total which is an int

Answer (score 0):

I modified your inventory function, now it contains a list before the loop start and it holds all the totals of the users that you are printing at the bottom of the loop, at the end using the `sum` function the grand total of all users can be calculated

```
def inventory(acct_info, months_subscribed, add_free_months, video_on_demand):
  print(acct_info)
  all_users_collection = []
  for info in acct_info:
   
    print('-')
          
    if info.get('months_subscribed') == 3:
        months_subscribed_total = info.get('months_subscribed') * 18
    elif info.get('months_subscribed') < 3:
        months_subscribed_total = info['months_subscribed'] * 7
    elif info.get('months_subscribed') > 3:
        months_subscribed_total = info['months_subscribed'] - 3 * 7 + 18

    print(f"User {info.get('name')} has months subscribed total of : $ {months_subscribed_total} ")

    if info['ad_free_months'] > 0:

      ad_free_total = info.get('ad_free_months') * 2 
      print(f" User {info.get('name')} total ad free is : {ad_free_total} ")

    if info['video_on_demand'] > 0:
      video_on_demand_total = info.get('video_on_demand') * 27.99
      
      print(f" User {info.get('name')} total video on demand is : {video_on_demand_total} ")



      acct_all_total = int(months_subscribed_total + ad_free_total + video_on_demand_total)
      acct_all_total = [int(acct_all_total)]
      all_users_collection.append(int(acct_all_total))
      print(f"Total for {info.get('name')} is: {acct_all_total} ")  



  acct_info = [{'name': 'acct_1', 'months_subscribed' : 2 , 'ad_free_months' : 3 , 'video_on_demand' : 1} ,
                        {'name': 'acct_2', 'months_subscribed' : 1 , 'ad_free_months' : 2 , 'video_on_demand' : 2},
                        {'name': 'acct_3', 'months_subscribed' : 2 , 'ad_free_months' : 1 , 'video_on_demand' : 3}] 


  combined_total = 0
  months_subscribed = 0
  ad_free_months = 0
  video_on_demand = 0
  months_subscribed_total = 0
  ad_free_total = 0 
  video_on_demand_total = 0
  inventory(acct_info, months_subscribed, ad_free_months, video_on_demand)
  acct_all_total = 0
  print('Total for all users is', sum(all_users_collection))
```

The other approach can be to use a single variable and increment for every total of a user at the end you will get total of all users